# Correct way to define "DATA" for object.material_slots in a single bpy call

Tags: python

I am quite happy with how the UI works now by calling a function I created for assigning the material to object or data:
[image]

```
class ApplyMaterialTo(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "material.data"
    bl_label = "Material Data"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.context.object.material_slots[0].link = 'DATA'
        return{'FINISHED'}


    row = layout.row()
    row.operator("material.object", text="Set Object Material")
    row.operator("material.data", text="Set Data Material")
```

But I feel my approach is pretty convoluted. SO I tried to apply what I learned to day but this does not work:

```
row.operator("object.material_slots[0]").link=DATA
```

The resulting error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\info\Desktop\Claas UI.blend\Claas_UI_2.py", line 174, in draw
NameError: name 'DATA' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error is that you are passing `DATA` a variable instead of string `"DATA"`, hence you get `DATA` is not defined.

The second thing is `object.material_slots[0]` is not an operator, all operators resides in `bpy.ops. ...`  it is a variable,  when you write `row.operator("object.material_slots[0]")` it will try to call `bpy.ops.object.material_slots[0]` which doesn't exist.

you may want to make your own operator ( if there's none that can do this) and use it instead.

For this case it would be easier to let prop() handle this easily :

```
row.prop(object.material_slots[0], "link")
```

and it will display a combobox that you can chose from

Comment: Ok great that answered my question. I am using the approach to create my own operator. Thank you very much for clarification.

Comment: @ClaasKuhnen you are welcome